# How to set a text equal to a number (variable) in excel and substitute?

Tags: excel

I want to set unique ID numbers equal to residue names in excel (based on a list of data). I am manipulating data using the ID numbers. When I obtain the list of numbers in the end, I want to convert them to corresponding residue names.

I have raw data as following:

[image]

The texts are residue names while the numbers are unique ID numbers.
In the picture above, I highlighted all the redundant data.

I wanted all unique residue-residue combinations, so I removed the duplicate ID number combinations. Below, in columns F and G, is the resulting list of unique ID# - ID# combinations:

[image]

What I want to do now is convert these ID numbers into the residue name they corresponded to, as in picture 1. For example, MET corresponded to number 363, and TYR to 33. As an example, above in columns I and J is the final result which I got by manual substitution.

I will be doing this for over a hundred lists of data. Anyone have any ideas for code, formulas, or ways to help me make this number-to-text substitution?

Many thanks.

Comment: Use an index/Match in I3: `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F3,B:B,0))` and in J3 `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G3,D:D,0))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, why not post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @devuxer, I just did, but I was unsure if the OP wanted to have the cells interior color also painted.  I was waiting for the follow up to decide.

Comment: Did my answer below work for you? If so please mark it as correct. It is something only you can do and it will close it out.

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

In I3:

```
 =INDEX(A:A,MATCH(F3,B:B,0))
```

In J3

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(G3,D:D,0))
```

Then copy down.